# Can a planar tangle have an infinite number of input disks?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, knot-theory, planar-algebras

Can a planar tangle have an infinite number of input disks?

Some publications talk about cases with a finite number of input disks, while others do not say if it is finite or infinite.

So, is it necessary/required that a planar tangle has a finite number of input disks?

Answer (score 3):

Yes finitely many disks.  Anything that forgets to say that is in error (my apologies if it’s my papers).

One way to understand why is by thinking about the 1-dimensional case.  The 2-box space of a “linear algebra” (algebra for the operad of 1-dimensional tangles) is just an ordinary associative algebra, and your question is whether one should allow infinite products in rings.